# Laravel reset password route not working

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am building custom views to reset passwords.
The routes looks like this:

```
  Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.reset');
  Route::post('password/email', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');
  Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset.token');
  Route::post('password/reset', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset');
```

In `ResetPasswordController.php` I have added this:

```
//Show form to seller where they can reset password
    public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
    {
        return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
            ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
        );
    }
```

The link sent to me looks like this:

```
https://myapp.dev/password/reset?451c70284a9d4b41123c4ec3efe83602b6cb955427ac48835200a45980bcf9f3
```

If I now enter that link I will go straight to the **password/reset** view and not the **password/reset/{token}**

However if I change the link in my broswer to

`https://myapp.dev/password/reset/451c70284a9d4b41123c4ec3efe83602b6cb955427ac48835200a45980bcf9f3`  **(changing "?" to "/")** I it works

So why doesnt the ? version of the URL work? I am using laravel 5.5

And since I dotn use the Auth:routes() is there any way to see what routes laravel generates when you use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different things with parameters.

1. Route Parameters: These are included in the routes with '/' as in your example. You can get them by:

   `$request->parameter('parameter_name');
   $request->parameters(); // for all parameters`
2. Request Parameters: These are request parameters which attached in the URL after '?'. Parameters are sent this way in GET request. You can get them by:

   `$request->input('parameter_name');
   $request->all(); // for all parameters`

Comment: How should I then change my code in order to get ``Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset.token');`` to work?

Comment: Have you customised the email template or using laravel's default?

Comment: I use Laravel default

Comment: `Auth::routes()` are defined in `Illuminate/Routing/Router.php`'s `auth()` function. compare your route with those routes and it might solve the problem. Laravel defines the token route as `password.reset`

Answer (score 0):

Laravel [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters)..

Probably you are confused with **required parameters** and **optional parameters**.

When you are defining the following route..

```
  Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset.token');
```

Laravel expects the `token` value as a required parameter in the third segment of the route.

But when you are accessing the route as

> https://myapp.dev/password/reset?451c70284a9d4b41123c4ec3efe8360..

There is only two segment for the route. The token value is assigned as the `get` parameter or optional parameter.
As you already defined as follows..

```
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.reset');
```

your generated link points to the `password/reset` and `?451c70284a9d4b41123c4ec3efe83602b6cb955427ac48835200a45980bcf9f3` value is  passed as the `get` parameter.

To trigger your reset the following route

```
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset.token');
```

you should use the following link format

> https://myapp.dev/password/reset/451c70284a9d4b41123c4ec3efe83602b6cb955427ac48835200a45980bcf9f3

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in your route

```
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.reset');
```

will take precedence over your url. since the route was declared on top and thus will goes into that showLinkRequestForm function first.

Meanwhile in your '/{token}' it will take slashes with the value that you sent thru the get route. Which currently you get.

```
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset.token');
```

Note that, position of route declaration is also affecting . Given example of 2 route with the same url but different name

```
//1st password/reset
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.reset');

//2nd password/reset 
Route::get('password/reset', 'Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showTokenForm')->name('password.reset.form');
```

In that case route naming will take the latest/last declaration which is 2nd password/reset and the first password/reset will be ignored or made into not available (tested).

So to answer your question which you asking Muhammad Nauman :

"How should I then change my code in order to get given route to work?"

```
Route::get('password/reset/{token}', 
'Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset.token');
```

In blade template you can adjust your routing value looks like this

```
<a href="{{route('password.reset.token',['token'=> $token_value ])}}">Reset Form</a>
```

Inside your new ResetPasswordController.php

```
public function showResetForm(Request $request)
{
    $token = $request->route()->parameter('token');

    return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
        ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
    );
}
```

But if you are kinda like doing dirty way which pass the GET request token email
"?token="somevalue"&email="somevalue" you could do something like this

```
public function showResetForm()
{
  return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
        ['token' => request('token'), 'email' => request('email')]
    );
}
```

Then in the blade you add additional routing  parameter of email too

```
<a href="{{route('password.reset.token',['token'=> $token_value,'email'=> $user->email ])}}">Reset Form</a>
```